# Determine whether a cell value's first character is numeric or text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to find a good way to use Excel to determine whether a cell's first character is a number or a letter. I am using this to determine a flag that gets marked or not depending on the answer. Here is an example table:

```
**Status    Code**
Inactive    2AJ
Active      ALO
Active      PN9
Active      Y2Y
Inactive    1P9
```

Essentially, if the beginning character of the **Code** column is a numeric value, the **Status** column should show "Inactive". Currently I have this and it doesn't work:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(B1,1)),"Inactive","Active")
```

Comment: Try `=IF(ISNUMBER(--LEFT(B1)),"Inactive","Active")`.`LEFT` function defaults to a single character.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Formula:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B2,1))),"Inactive","Active")`

You were trying to see if a number stored as a string was a number.  This fixes that issue.

Comment: @JoshuaBurton, if it worked, please mark it with the green check mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(CODE(LEFT(B2,1))>47,CODE(LEFT(B2,1))<58),"Inactive","Active")
```

copied down to suit.

This might then be compared against the ColumnA values to flag any discrepancies.

Comment: Somebody has downmarked the solution using the CODE function, maybe thinking it's implementation dependent e.g. won't work on a Mac. I think it will because the first 128 ASCII characters are supposed to be the same on a Mac. Only other comment at risk of being nit-picking, CODE looks at the first character of a string so =IF(AND(CODE(B2)>47,CODE(B2)<58),"Inactive","Active") would suffice.

Comment: Good point, have to think about a solution being adaptable as well as answering the current question.